# How to access json data property in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json that is similar to the code below.

```
var jsonData = {
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Cpuset": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "HOME=/root"
        ]
        "Hostname": "git",
        "WorkingDir": ""
    },
    "Created": "2015-03-03T08:59:05.735601013Z",
    "Name": "/git",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Ports": {
            "22/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "2008"
                }
            ],
            "80/tcp": null,
            "8006/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "9008"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "ResolvConfPath": "/etc/resolv.conf",
    "State": {
        "Pid": 6146,
        "Running": true,
        "StartedAt": "2015-03-03T08:59:05.829535361Z"
    }
}
```

As you can see any properties has it's own unique name. My question is: How can I access the properties like `Env` in this way `getValue(jsonData, 'Env');` ?

My json is much bigger and more complex than what I put above.

Comment: `getValue()` is yours ?

Comment: yes sir. I want to show you what i want

Comment: Are you asking us to write `getValue` for you?

Comment: I search about this but i can't find any npm package or lib to do something like this generally. I want to know is any lib or package do something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that allows you to recurse through an object to find the information you need if you don't know the structure of the object. Note that this will break out of the function when the *first instance of that key has been found*. This means that if you have more than one key called `HostIp`, it will only find the first one.

```
function getValue(obj, key) {
    var found = null;
    var recurse = function (obj, key) {
        for (var p in obj) {
            if (p === key) {
                found = obj[p];
                break;
            }
            if (obj[p] !== null && typeof obj[p] === 'object') recurse(obj[p], key);
        }
    }
    recurse(obj, key);
    return found;
}

getValue(jsonData, 'Env'); // [ "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin…", "HOME=/root" ]
```

If you want to find all instances of a particular key name use the following code instead. It will add all matches to an array and return that array once the object has been trawled. This isn't particularly useful tho because it doesn't provide the context in which it found the key, but it might give you a few ideas.

```
function getValue(obj, key) {
    var found = [];
    var recurse = function (obj, key) {
        for (var p in obj) {
            if (p === key) {
                found.push(obj[p]);
            }
            if (obj[p] !== null && typeof obj[p] === 'object') recurse(obj[p], key);
        }
    }
    recurse(obj, key);
    return found;
}

getValue(jsonData, 'HostPort'); // [ "2008", "9008" ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jf1gpr4f/2/)

Comment: Well, whatever, nice answer anyway.